# Shallow Copy Objects containing Generics Lists

Tags: c#, shallow-copy

How can we copy data from an object to a DTO Object if the objects have a List in it, or are a list of T object?

I am currently using this, however I have to really to a lot of work to still Shallow Copy the object to my DTO:
[How would you improve this shallow copying class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469982/how-would-you-improve-this-shallow-copying-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) a look, it's faster than doing reflection and pretty easy to configure.

Comment: +1 for AutoMapper. This is a solved problem, there is no point in re-solving it.

Comment: Automapper is so bloated though.  I was hoping for a small revision of the code.

Comment: Sounds like you have a case of the NIH's. That is to say "Not Invented Here". Automapper has lots of features yes, but it is very quick at doing what it does. And most of those features have been implemented as a result of thousands of programmers putting hundreds of thousands of man hours into using the product. It is very likely that you will spend less time learning to use Automapper than writing your own mapping program, and when you find you need more than just a shallow copy, that feature will already be there.